# Using /dev/urandom for dd(disk performance) test is a good idea or not?

Tags: unix, centos, dd

to test the disk performance I have triggered dd test.when I used /dev/urandom/ as input file I am getting very low performance

```
   dd if=/dev/urandom of=file_01.txt bs=8K count=3000
   3000+0 records in
   3000+0 records out
   24576000 bytes (25 MB) copied, 3.16523 s, 7.8 MB/s
```

But when used some other file its giving very high performance.

```
   dd if=/root/test.dbg of=file_0521.txt bs=8K count=3000
   3000+0 records in
   3000+0 records out
   24576000 bytes (25 MB) copied, 0.0606644 s, 405 MB/s
```

How can I bridge the gap between these two numbers. Is it good to use /dev/urandom/ for DD test.which numbers I have consider to benchmark.why is /dev/urandom giving very low performance value.

Answer (score 4):

You are benchmarking `/dev/urandom` (see [random(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html)), not your disk or `dd`. It is doing some significant processing inside the kernel (basically mixing some real random source with an in-kernel [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)).

You could use `hdparm` to benchmark your disk. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108839/50557).

If you insist on benchmarking your disk with `dd`, make once a big file in some *tmpfs* filesystem (perhaps using `dd` or `head` on `/dev/urandom`), then benchmark `dd` to copy that temporary file to your disk.

BTW, to benchmark a disk, you need to bypass any [file-system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) (and write to a raw partition on that disk), since if you are using a file in a file system on that disk, most of the work is related to [page cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) -used by the file system layer in the kernel- and the disk is not really used immediately, see also [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html)..